Diagonalizing a matrix in $k[x]_x$ using row operations over $k[x]$ and column operations over $k[1/x]$
Gortz-Wedhorn theorem 11.50 : Let $M$ be an invertible matrix in $GL_n(k[x]_x)$ where $k$ is a field (actually I think the proof should work if $k$ is a ring as well). Then, $M$ can be transformed by invertible row operations in $k[x]$ and invertible column operations in $k[1/x]$ into a matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} d_1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
 0 & d_2 & ... & 0 \\ 
...& ... & ... & ... \\
 0 & 0 & ... & d_n \end{pmatrix}$$
The first step in the proof is to consider the first column. Let $v$ be the minimum of the $x$-adic valuations of entries in the first column, and use invertible row operations to transform the first column into $(a, 0, 0, ..., 0)^T$, where the valuation of $a$ is $v$.
How to do this? I don't think this is possible. For example, let $u,v =-3/2 \pm \sqrt{5}/2$. These are the roots of $(x+1)(x+2)-1$. consider the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x+1 & x-v\\
x-u& x+2
\end{pmatrix}$$
The determinant is 1 so this is invertible in $GL_n(k[x]_x)$ but I don't know how to make the bottom left entry zero.

Are you assuming that $u$ and $v$ are elements of the base ring $k$ here? If so, then subtract row 2 from row 1, multiply row 1 through by $1/(1+u)$ and you have a 1 in the top left, right?
